# Bobbin with $I=I_{0}\sin(\Omega t)$

Tags: maxwell-equations

If I have an infinite bobbin with $I=I_{0}\sin(\Omega t), \mu$ and $n=N/L$ using Ampère and supposing that $d\vec{D}/dt=\vec{0}$ I have found that 
$$\vec{B}=n\mu I_{0}\sin(\Omega t)\vec{e_{z}}$$

But the problem is that $\vec{\nabla} \times \vec{E}=-d \vec{B}/dt$ is not $\vec{0}$ so $\vec{E}$ is not $\vec{0}$ and $d \vec{D}/dt$ is also not zero.

Where is the problem?
Is $I$ equivalent to $\vec{J_{D}}$ and not $\vec{J_{f}}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two solutions to this:

1. Ampère can only be used in case of a current uniform in time, thus you wont get this problem.
2. Actually alhough Ampère can only be used with a uniform current, I have just recently read an article (unfortunately only available in Hungarian) that the Biot-Savart law is also true if $\frac{\text{d}\vec{\mathbf{D}}}{\text{d}t}$ is not zero. By Biot-Savart you get the same expression for the solenoid as with Ampère, but it shows that expression for it will also be true if there is displacement current density, thus again, it will not be a problem.

**UPDATE:** I have found an English language article giving the derivation, available [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.170.2351&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

Comment: Wow! Maxwell does not work and the solution is valid?

Comment: @Sergi Ampère's law is not the true Maxwell's equation. Ampère's law reads as $\oint \vec{B}d\vec{r}=\int \vec{J}d\vec{F}$. But this law is actually incorrect: you can't even handle a simple capacitor with it, and it is inconsistent with the law of charge conservation. You need to add another current density, the displacement current density, to get a valid law: $\oint \vec{B}d\vec{r}=\int \vec{J} + \frac{d\vec{D}}{dt}d\vec{F}$. But in case of a static current, $\frac{d\vec{D}}{dt}$ is zero, thus Ampère's is fine. It happens that for a solenoid the static case and non-static case are the same.

Comment: @Sergi I have updated the answer with a derivation of Biot-Savart's law using displacement current, I suggest you read it.